# Why is the US envoy to Haiti criticising the US support for Ariel Henry as prime-minister of Haiti?

Tags: united-states, election, prime-minister, assassinations, haiti

According to the recent Democracy Now article, titled, *Haiti Envoy Resigns Over Mass Deportations, Blasts History of US Interventions*, Daniel Foote, the US envoy to Haiti wrote in his resignation letter,:

> I will not be associated with the US inhumane, counter-productive decision to deport thousands of Haitian refugees.

And

> This cycle of international political interventions in Haiti has consistently produced catastrophic results.

Moreover, he criticises the Biden administration's support for Ariel Henry as prime-minister after the assassination of Jovenal Moise, the president of Haiti, in July of this year.

**Q. Why is Daniel Foote criticising this support? Is this simply because he feels the US should not interfere in Haiti's internal affairs - or is there some more specific reason**

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [because](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/9/23/us-envoy-to-haiti-rings-over-inhumane-deportations-of-haitians) Foote considers Henry unelected:

> Foote criticised a recent statement of support for “the unelected, de facto Prime minister Dr. Ariel Henry” and said Haitians need the opportunity “to chart their own course, without international puppeteering and favored candidates but with genuine support for that course”.